# Using Google.Protobuf in .NET 4.6 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, protocol-buffers

I'm relatively new to C#, .NET and protobuf, so I'm not totally up to snuff on what is possible in terms of backwards compatibility. I'm working a project targeting .NET 4.6.1, and I'd like to use [Google's C# protobuf implementation](https://github.com/google/protobuf), but when I try to install through the Nuget Package Manager, I get told that I can't install the package because I'm targeting 4.6.1 and protobuf appears to be built for 4.5.

What are my options? I'd looked into using protobuf-net, but I unfortunately have proto3 .proto files, and the proto compiler included in protobuf-net doesn't appear to support proto3.

Comment: It should be absolutely fine to install in a 4.6.1 or 4.6.2 (you mention both) project. Could you give as many details as possible about your project? (What version of Visual Studio are you using, what kind of library, etc?) If you could provide a [mcve] in terms of a walkthrough "File/New project, select project type X, add dependency Y" that would be great.

Comment: (I've just tried doing this myself, with a console application targeting .NET 4.6.1, then using the NuGet package manager UI to add Google.Protobuf version 3.2.0, and it was absolutely fine.)

Comment: Huh -- I will try to spin up a small example. Interestingly, the most recent version of Google.Protobuf I can see in the package manager is 2.6.1.1. I'm in VS2015.

Comment: See here https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/csharp/src/AddressBook/Program.cs

Comment: I suspect you're trying Google.ProtocolBuffers; you want Google.Protobuf. Although Google.ProtocolBuffers has a latest version of 2.4.1.555. I don't know *which* library you're looking at with a version of 2.6.1.1...

Comment: John - could you provide a link to the nuget package you're installing? I found one called "protobuf3" which appears to solve my problem but it's version 3.1.

Comment: Oh, I think I found the right one via Taha's answer.

Comment: My confusion I guess stemmed from not typing "Google.Protobuf" into the search box (I used simply "protobuf" instead). Thanks for the help all - I feel very silly.

Comment: No need to say thank its my pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example on Git which uses command line.

[Git Protocol Buffer in C#](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/csharp/src/AddressBook/Program.cs)

You can add Protocol buffer namespace from Here on nuget

[Protocol Buffer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf)

Comment: Accepting this, but wanted to add this comment to clarify the confusion for anyone who might stumble upon this in the future -- searching "protobuf" through NuGet will yield misleading packages that aren't the official Google package. Try searching the literal package name "Google.Protobuf" if searching through Nuget.